# Should I create a new EBS volume from a public snapshot or from my brand new one in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, snapshot

I am launching an instance in AWS and want to add addition storage. Should I create a new EBS volume from a public snapshot or from my brand new one in AWS?

What is the difference from a public snapshot and my brand new EBS volume?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the volume to be blank, then you would use new volume.

There are snapshots that contain things like public data sets. Using those snapshots allow you to get that data without having to download it yourself.

Some examples are here: http://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a blank EBS volume you do not need a snapshot at all, just create a blank volume, and create a new file system on it.